# Forcing std::tuple to contain std::pair<fixed_type, T>

Tags: c++, stdtuple

Is it possible to use `std::tuple` "partly specialized" so that it contains `std::pair<fixed_t, T>` with varying T?

UPD: the tuple should *contain the pairs*. So it is equivalent to using an array of `fixed_t` together with a regular `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use variadic tempate alias and parameter pack expansion:

```
template<typename... Types>
using fixed_tuple = std::tuple< std::pair<fixed_t, Types>... >;
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f04ae866abf6f8c6)